# Android- Listening and interpreting which app sent notification?

Tags: android-notifications, android, android-notification-bar

I'm building an android app which listens to notifications and has to figure out which app (Facebook, whatsapp, mail, etc.) the notification belongs to.

I know how to listen to the notification using NotificationListenerService. 
But how do I figure out which app sent this notification?

Comment: can you put your code what you've done already with NotificationListenerService

Comment: Do you know what apps you're specifically looking for?  If so you would just cross check the package name.

Comment: Facebook, whatsapp, bbm, mail, calls mostly. Okay how do I go about doing that using NotificationListenerService?